# Dividir número de telefone que vem de de um arquivo html e dividir o mesmo em dois

Tags: c#

Recebo um campo numérico em um `html` que vem assim `"413232123441999993254"` que no caso seriam dois números de telefone com `DDD 41`, ambos entram no campo Telefone:, gostaria de dividir esses números em dois para ficar mais organizado.
Estou usando `C#` para o desenvolvimento desta aplicação, já tenho o método Telefone que captura desse `html` o número telefônico preciso agora dividir ele em dois mas sei como fazer.
Segue abaixo método telefone como é hoje:

```
   public string Telefone(string pContent)
    {

        var content = BuscaSimples(pContent, 
            "Telefone: </span><span style=\"font-size: 18px; color:black;\">",
            "</span>");

        if (content.Empty())
            content = BuscaSimples(pContent, "<a href=\"tel:\" style=\"color:#0082c8\">", "</a>");

        if (content.Empty())
            content = BuscaSimples(pContent, "Tel.: ", "</span>");


        return content;
    }
```

Comment: Você sabe ou não sabe como fazer?

Comment: dá uma olhanda no [`substring`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Primeiro, por que você recebe ou captura os telefones dessa forma? Isso me parece um tanto incomum.

Answer (score 3):

pode usar o substring, o primeiro digito é quantos caracteres tu quer pular da string e o segundo é quantos caracteres tu quer pegar a partir do primeiro parâmetro.

```
string texto = "413232123441999993254";
var telefone1 = texto.Substring(0,10);
var telefone2 = texto.Substring(10, 11);
```

Answer (score 1):

Se os números de telefone fixo e celular vierem sempre na mesma ordem, a solução do @RafaelScheffer atende.

Caso venham às vezes em ordem trocada, fazer assim:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Telefones(string pContent)
{
    ...

    var re = 
        new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[1-9]\d([0-8]\d{7}|9\d{8})");

    var matches = re.Matches(content);

    if (matches.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            yield return match.Value;
        }
    }
}
```